# Make the <kbd> tags display in the android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, keyboard, keyboard-glyphs

When viewing a question/answer with kbd tags the graphic isn't displayed. (Note that the text within is).

For an example (can you guess which one it is?) see here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71407/161467

Can keyboard images be added?

Comment: Congrats on very few display issues in the formatting sandbox though!! I recognise this is a pretty minor issue with (I guess) quite a tricky fix.

Comment: +1 yes it should be there in app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was added into the application in version 0.1.34.